# Windows 10 how to create shadow storage on another drive without vssadmin create

Tags: windows-10, volume-shadow-service

I want to create shadow storage for one drive on another using Windows 10.
For server windows editions, there is:

```
vssadmin add shadowstorage /for=<ForVolumeSpec> /on=<OnVolumeSpec> [/maxsize=<MaxSizeSpec>]
```

The add command is missing in Windows 10, how would one go about it?

There are some Powershell commands available, but I could not make them work.

```
(Get-WmiObject -list win32_ShadowStorage).Create('C:\','D:\','3000000000')
```

Comment: clients don't support this only server editions.

Comment: Clients don't support the command, sure, it says so on teachnet, but the functionality, I'm not so sure?

Comment: the code for server and client is the same, but some features/commands are not licensed for client and simply don't work. use feedback hub app and send feedback, hope for a lot of votes and that MS enables it for clients in future Windows 10 Versions

Comment: Alternative command `wmic shadowstorage call create Volume=C:\ DiffVolume=D:\ MaxSpace=1073741824` does not work neither - returns *unknown error* `ReturnValue = 10;`.

Comment: This feature might be related to *Transportable shadow copies* feature, in which case it is available only on server editions according to [Supported Operating System Versions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636(v=ws.10).aspx#Anchor_9).

Answer (score -1):

VSSAdmin only has the "create" option on a Windows Server. Instead, you will have to make use of a PowerShell script to create the shadow.

powershell.exe -Command (gwmi -list win32_shadowcopy).Create('E:\','ClientAccessible')

Since this just makes use of the [Win32_ShadowCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394428(v=vs.85).aspx) class in WMI, you can use other methods to create the shadow. This includes the "[wmic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx)" utility.

wmic shadowcopy call create Volume='E:\'

Comment: The question is about how to create shadow storage ([Win32_ShadowStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394433(v=vs.85).aspx)), not about how to create snapshot ([Win32_ShadowCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394428(v=vs.85).aspx)).